# Parsing large amount of XML data in NTEXT or NVARCHAR field

Tags: sql, xml-parsing, ssis

I have a huge amount of XML data  stored in NTEXT and NVARCHAR(MAX) field. I need to parse this data. But am not able to do so with the CAST or CONVERT function. This is the error message I am getting : 
Msg 9400, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 XML parsing: line 1, character 30000, unexpected end of input

Example of my XML data in DB (almost 64K characters):
PT0S00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsefirstNameEz00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalselastName1Elum0d3f106d-cf33-4562-b722-625acec9dc02a2e20551-8c98-48dc-8342-b5516a8583f40001-01-01T00:00:00P90D00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseemailAddressez@elum.com00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseconfirmEmailAddressez@elum.com00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseallowFirstPartyContacttrue00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseallowThirdPartyContactfalsee501dc4b-98df-4569-bb75-9ffd9afe6ce81f14a091-1309-4316-bc6c-2dc45cd8e2650001-01-01T00:00:00PT0S00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsecountryCodeUS00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseaddressLine1Data Data Data00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseaddressLine2Data Data Data00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseaddressLine3Data Data Data00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsecityPhoenix00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseregionId99300000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsepostalCode6541200000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseallowFirstPartyContacttrue00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseallowThirdPartyContactfalse00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseregionArizona9f43b5e1-2043-4644-871e-5619f255debedeedf743-e9fd-414f-922c-2770be87d87e0001-01-01T00:00:00PT0S00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsedepartmentNameData Data Data00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsejobTitleData Data Data00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsecountryCodeUS00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseaddressLine1Data Data Data00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseaddressLine2Data Data Data00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseaddressLine3Data Data Data00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsecityPhoenix00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseregionId99300000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsepostalCode6541200000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseallowFirstPartyContacttrue00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseallowThirdPartyContactfalse00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseregionArizona1c76ee4e-aa64-4441-9dea-cd7fea056e317d5d2708-d09b-48cb-a168-e9eabee535fb0001-01-01T00:00:00PT0S00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsecountryCodeUS00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsecountryDialingCode+100000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseareaCode00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0Sfalsenumber00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsettyStatusFalsefalse00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseallowFirstPartyContacttrue00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseallowThirdPartyContactfalse6e3c00b1-97bc-4477-98d8-b383d8b37ebe7af5e0ca-fc1d-4177-a735-9bd2a9af22b60001-01-01T00:00:00PT0S00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsecountryCodeUS00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsecountryDialingCode+100000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseareaCode23400000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0Sfalsenumber23234200000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0Sfalseextension00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsettyStatusFalsefalse00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseallowFirstPartyContacttrue00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseallowThirdPartyContactfalse10d8b3b3-81d1-463c-8abe-a8b0ea52546f3b11dd5c-fcde-4f3b-8adb-4ca52b246ce50001-01-01T00:00:00PT0S00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsecountryCodeUS00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsecountryDialingCode+100000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseareaCode23400000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0Sfalsenumber232342300000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsettyStatusFalsefalse00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseallowFirstPartyContactfalse00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseallowThirdPartyContactfalse755efb54-6d98-4a58-8c4b-623b368f232471b34622-291c-43ff-a72a-42207091a1f90001-01-01T00:00:00PT0S00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000Please Select from the Following OptionsPT0SfalsePlease Select from the Following Optionsfalsefalsecac80052-56c0-4817-85b5-dca33417efc300000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000160001-01-01T00:00:00PT0S00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsedepartmentNameData Data Data00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsejobTitleData Data Data00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsecountryCodeUS00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseaddressLine1Data Data Data00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseaddressLine2Data Data Data00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseaddressLine3Data Data Data00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsecityPhoenix00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseregionId99300000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsepostalCode6541200000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseallowFirstPartyContacttrue00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseallowThirdPartyContactfalse00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseregionArizona6663fcc6-04ae-4a43-b9e9-790a0a9c762d4d2649af-698d-49b7-a025-2c28e1c955e90001-01-01T00:00:00PT0S00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsedepartmentName00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsejobTitle00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalsecountryCodeUS00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseaddressLine100000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseaddressLine200000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0SfalseaddressLine300000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000PT0Sfalsecity00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Comment: The XML you have posted is missing some closing tags in the end. That can be because you errored when posting your question or it could be because that is actually how the XML is stored in your table. If the latter is true you would get the error message you have posted so my guess would be that you have stored invalid XML in your table.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Xquery to query xml data . Xquery is supported by all major databases and W3C recommended. [Start here](http://www.w3schools.com/xquery/xquery_intro.asp)

Comment: I need to do the parsing in T-SQL

Comment: And the problem I am facing is when i try casting the NVARCHAR column as XML I get an unexpected end of input error.